# Animating object in Blender not rotating along edge correctly / strangely (see video)

Tags: object, animation, rotation, blender

I’m trying to create an animated folding box in Blender 2.81a but the objects (the sides of the box that i’m trying to fold) act incorrectly ([see video](https://youtu.be/N66hxPtb6iI)). I want to move and rotate objects to new positions. The keys are set with LocRot. As you see in the video the edges disconnect halfway the rotation, and get back together in the end.

I don’t know why this is happening, as the 3D cursor and the rotation point is located on the edge.
I’ve also tried rotation with an empty, like on the first “fold”, but then the second fold jumps away to another location. I also got stuck using armatures.

Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying to animate chain of objects, the correct way to do it is to chain them with parent relation and set their origins to the useful position where the bends are. Then you can animate the chain just by animation rotation of its segment.

The strucutre could be set like this:

[image]

See how the Bottom object has its origin set to its bottom, then Middle object is child of the Bottom and its origin is right at the bend. Similarly Top objects is child of the Middle.

You can set origin of object by setting cursor to the right position in edit mode and then in object mode using menu Object -> Set origin -> Set to cursor. Parent relation is set by selectin any objects and then using menu Object -> Parent -> Object. The last selected object will be the parent.

The problem with your setup is that you are trying manualy transfer animation of location through the chain which is what the parent relation is for. And the weird rotation you have is probably caused by interpolation of matrices. Maybe if you would switch you rotation to Quaternions it will work, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: This solves my problem! Thank you so much for the effort of rebuilding my set-up and the explanation! 
I had to parent the top to the middle, and the middle to the bottom. Now it works smoothly without the objects acting weird. I don't know what Quaternions can do for me (yet) but i'll keep this in mind for future problems :)
Thanks again!